# DJANGO DRF, Serializar modelos relacionados

Tags: django, djangorestframework, serialización

Mi problema es el siguiente:

En mi app tengo los siguientes modelos dentro del 'models.py'

```
class Carrera(models.Model):
     nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Materia(models.Model):
     nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     nivel = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     carrera = models.ForeignKey(Carrera)
```

El serilizers.py

```
class Carrera_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Carrera
        fields = ('id', 'nombre')

class Materia_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model =  Materia
        fields = ('nombre', 'nivel', 'carrera')
```

Las url son:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'plan/mat', api.Materia_ViewSet)
router.register(r'plan/car', api.Carrera_ViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

El JSON mostrado cuando ingreso a http://localhost:8000/plan/mat/ es el siguiente:

```
        {
        "nombre": "Ing Civil I",
        "nivel": 1,
        "carrera": 1
        },
```

Y quisiera que muestre:

```
{
"nombre": "Ing Civil I",
"nivel": 1,
"carrera": {"nombre": "Ing Civil"
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/plan/car/1/"
           }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el modelo de la siguiente forma:

```
class Materia(models.Model):
     nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     nivel = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     carrera = models.ForeignKey(Carrera,related_name='carrera')
```

con `related_name` hacemos la especie de JOIN en Materia_Serializer [1](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

```
class Materia_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 carrera = Carrera_Serializer(source='carrera', read_only=True)
 class Meta:
    model =  Materia
    fields = ('nombre', 'nivel', 'carrera')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! me ayudo mucho, es la primera api que estoy haciendo, y la verdad q estaba medio perdido con eso.